# Polynomial Evaluation (Horner’s Method)

Tags: assembly, mips

So the teacher give me the problem:
Write a program that computes the value of a polynomial using Horner’s method. The
coefficients of the polynomial are stored in an array of single precision floating point values:

```
 .data:
n: 5
a: .float 4.3, -12.4, 6.8, -0.45, 3.6
```

The size and the values in the array may change. Write the program to initialize a sum
to zero and then loop n times. Each execution of the loop, with loop counter j, does the
following:
sum = sum ∗ x + a[j]
To test and debug this program, start with easy values for the coefficients

I have done this code

```
.data
n : .word 5
a : .float 4.3, -12.4, 6.8, -0.45, 3.6

.text

main:
     li $s0, 0                  #x=0
     lw $s1, a($0)              #i=0

     lwc1 $f1, ($s1) #f1=a(i)
     add.s $f2, $f0, $f1 #x=x+f1
     addi $s0, $s0, 1 #i=i+1

     lw $s1, a($s0) #i=0
     lwc1 $f1, 0($s1) #f1=a(i)
     mul.s $f2, $f2, $f12 #x=x*x
     add.s $f2, $f2, $f1 #x=x+f1
     addi $s0, $s0, 1 #i=i+1

     lw $s1, a($s0) #i=0
     lwc1 $f1, 0($s1) #f1=a(i)
     mul.s $f2, $f2, $f12     #x=x*x
     add.s $f2, $f2, $f1     #x=x+f1
     addi $s0, $s0, 1 #i=i+1

     lw $s1, a($s0) #i=0
     lwc1 $f1, 0($s1) #f1=a(i)
     mul.s $f2, $f2, $f12 #x=x*x
     add.s $f2, $f2, $f1 #x=x+f1
     
     addi $s0, $s0, 1 #i=i+1
     lw $s1, a($s0) #i=0
     lwc1 $f1, 0($s1) #f1=a(i)
     mul.s $f2, $f2, $f12 #x=x*x
     add.s $f2, $f2, $f1 #x=x+f1
     s.s $f2, 0($s1) #a(i)=f2
     j main
```

It seems like the program didn't running. Did i do something wrong ?

Comment: Please describe what it does and how it differs from what you expect.